# Python 3.6.3 - Send MozillaCookieJar File and read HTML source code

Tags: python-3.x, http, cookies

I'm very fresh about python (i'm learning just about 1 day long).

I need to send cookies (i got them from my Google Chrome browser to a *.text file) and be redirected after login to my account page, to after read a source HTML code do what i wanna do. With much searches allong internet, i already have this piece of code:

```
import os
import time
import urllib.request
import http.cookiejar

while 1:
  cj = http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar('cookies.txt')
  cj.load()
  print(len(cj))  # output: 9
  print(cj)  # output: <MozillaCookieJar[<Cookie .../>, <Cookie .../>, ... , <Cookie .../>]>
  for cookie in cj:
    cookie.expires = time.time() + 14 * 24 * 3600
  cookieProcessor = urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj)
  opener = urllib.request.build_opener(cookieProcessor)
  request = urllib.request.Request(url='https://.../')
  response = opener.open(request, timeout=100)
  s = str(response.read(), 'utf-8')
  print(s)
  if 'class' in s:
    os.startfile('test.mp3')
  time.sleep(5)
```

With this code i believe, hope i'm not be mistaken, have sending the cookies correctly. My main question is: How can i wait and catch the source HTML code after server redirect my login to personal page? I can't call again my Request with the same URL.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why don't you just use `requests` package and pass cookies ? (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies)

Comment: i followed your advise and now i'm using requests, really much easyer, thanks. Now the problem is, after i do this: `with requests.Session() as s:
            postRequest = s.post('https://...', data=payload)` and catch HTML with .text and do some stuffs, more ahead i need to get HTML of other page using same session, but doing `request2 = s.get('http://other page)` i get in HTML a mensage telling i have session deprecated. how can i workaround this?

Comment: if you get response then maybe some crlf-token is not passed. I'm sorry, I've did dozens of automations like that in my life and you have to know one thing - every page is different. Without source code of page and knowing what you want to achieve, I can not help you more. If you could create working poc then I will have a change to investigate

Comment: Okay, I believe that my question was not adequate for what I really intended. When I want to get the second page with the same session, in fact the URL remains the same, because the call is in AJAX, I need to pick up the HTML source code that comes up after this call:
`<a id="js_GlobalMenu" onclick="ajaxHandlerCall(this.href);return false;" href="?view=advisor" title="" class="normal">
                        <span class="smallFont"></span>
                    </a>`
I believe requests.get maybe not the correct procedure to get what I want

Comment: It depends on what `ajaxHandlerCall` really does, but if it just reloads content on page then there is no problem for getting html at all. You just have to get page `https://example.com/some_page?view=advisor`.

Comment: exactly, i had sucess just with the get(), still getting mensage with a session deprecated but i am able to get information that i need. Now i'm figuring out how to scraping html rendered by AJAX, i'm reading about PhantomJS...

Comment: Welcome to dirty world of buggy headless enginges which can be hard to work with :D PhantomJS is no longer supported (since few months) so maybe go for Selenium (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).